# how we can find out an calender event edited or updated on basis of their id

Tags: android, events, android-contentresolver

As i used content observer to detect change in calendar events but it called on any event change. so how can we detect which one event gets modified

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only get a URI to the change content (`onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)`), if it's known.

Maybe one of these posts will get you further:

[Android: How to get event and calendar id from Observer/Receiver for CalendarContract.EVENT removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823789/android-how-to-get-event-and-calendar-id-from-observer-receiver-for-calendarcon)

[What is the best way to handle updates when the calendar syncs new events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170903/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-updates-when-the-calendar-syncs-new-events)